After a fresh Xubuntu install on dual boot, I have an additional screen in display settings numbered 3 None-1-1

I am using two monitors in a dual boot system. A search showed a similar question but it related to a single monitor only. It could not solve my query as I was dealing with two monitors.
I had Windows 11 installed and installed Xubuntu 24.04.1 alongside it. This resulted in a spurious 3rd display None-1-1 appearing as shown in the picture.
In addition, the Primary Display with Desktop appears on my LH monitor.
I am using a VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate] (rev a1)
How can I get rid of the spurious display and have the Desktop on my Microstep monitor which is selected as the Primary Display?
Thank you.

This question is similar to: Unkown Display after install nvidia-driver-470 on Ubuntu 22.04. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have been able to move the panel and icons to the Primary Display. I used the 3 configure settings found by selecting the 'i' icon adjacent to the Primary Display option. I still cannot remove the spurious display.

It 'went away'!
No idea why, just ignored it and now don't see it.
I don't intend to look for it!

I had the same situation and my extra non-existent display which was showing in the Settings app went away too. I suspect it was due to an update.
